# One application and a huge difference in operation after different startup methods

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I create an application in Spring Boot https://github.com/JonkiPro/REST-Web-Services. The application can be launched in two ways. The first way is to start from the main home class https://github.com/JonkiPro/REST-Web-Services/blob/master/web/src/main/java/com/web/WebApplication.java. The application compiles as I expect and everything works without a problem https:// pastebin.com/xYTQtkp4.

However, when I run the application from the class https://github.com/JonkiPro/REST-Web-Services/blob/master/war/src/main/java/com/war/WarApplication.java this is drama. The application compiles https:// pastebin.com/D86wpghW, but almost nothing works. The compilation code is almost half as long. The WAR application does not find any controllers, any created beans, does not map addresses, undoes Spring Security to the default settings and when compiling shows`Using Generated security password: c7c7458d-a7f1-45e2-a871-007f80d4ea26` https://zapodaj.net/0a01ba8eee626.png.html. I have a method which during the compilation is added to the user database (it can be seen at the bottom in the first compilation, not WAR), then here in the WAR compilation I'm not running at all. Base H2 does not work. Nothing after this launch does not work. What's going on here? And yet in this module I will generate a WAR file to be placed on the server. It is a pity that nothing works.

Comment: No one is going to follow your pastebin links, or try and figure out what your question is here; it's just the way it is. You should [edit] this question and explain what you are trying to do, what you have tried (including a [mcve]), and what results you get. Everything should be text and inline. See [ask].

Comment: Why do you even have 2 different ways of starting? You should only have a single `WebApplication` or `WarApplication` that does both.

Comment: I took this idea from the Netflix project https://github.com/Netflix/genie/blob/master/genie-web/src/main/java/com/netflix/genie/GenieWeb.java https://github.com/Netflix/genie/blob/master/genie-war/src/main/java/com/netflix/genie/GenieWar.java